# intellij how to auto completion a class in string literal

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

I have defined a method like below:

```java
public void mehtod(String clazz) {
...
}
```

`clazz` parameter is a FQDN name as: `com.example.Hello`, and I want intellij to autocomplete when i type `"com.example.Hello"`.

Do I need to make some custom config in Intellij?

[image]

Comment: Do you expect IDE to complete the value of the String parameter and not in runtime? How would it know it? Otherwise, the question is not clear, please clarify.

Comment: as the image shows, when I type `cc`, intellij pops up package infos, and I want to intellij to do the same thing when I call `method("cc."`

Comment: Just type `Hello.class.getName()`. That will make it safe, auto-completable, refactorable, and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Class Name Completion" for this.
Ctrl-Option-Space on Mac, Ctrl-Alt-SPace on Windows
I agree with "JB Nizet", though: Use Hello.class.getName() is more reliable